# How to input variables in command prompt and compare the input variables with other variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt, argparse

I would like to first explain what this application/Python program does so that you have a better understanding of the problem. I am an absolute beginner in programming so please take it easy on my i have tried my best to explain it as vividly as i could.
This application will be used to test 4000 devices for there correct software hardware version and other information. How it does this is through the Web-server, each device has a 2D code(its like a barcode) which will be scanned, this scanned code contains the mac address and the ordernumber. firstly when i run the program on command prompt it should look like this :
[image: Example parameters]
I should be able to define what the desired variables are hence typing it manually in the command prompt EXCEPT for the scancode which will automatically appear when I used the 2D scanner and scan the code which will be on the device exterior. The scancode contains the devices mac address(last 12 digits) and the Order number(first 5 digits) i found out how to dissect it and compare it with the webserver's Mac address and order number.

Once i have defined the desired values for Order number Hardware version Software version etc these "desired" values need to be compared with the webserver values. (Please see my Python code for reference i take the webserver values through xml.dom and then compare it with the desired values to see if the values are correct.
So far i have only manually defined the desired values in the source code but I want to define them on the command prompt line after calling the programm "C:\Users\Barry\Automate main.py"
I hope you guys have understood the problem i am facing, I want to know if anyone can help me solve this task i have googled a so much about this but i cannot find out how to do it.
In the picture i have uploaded the values underlined in red are to be manually input and the blue one is the scan code which will automatically appear when I scan the device.
I tried several things with input() method but yeah it did not work out example:

```
print("./productionreview -output test.csv", "--desired-orderno = ",input(),  "--desired-hardwareversion = ",input(), "--desired-softwareversion = ",input()," --pc-praefix",input(), "--desired-device-type=",input(), "--scancode=", "58183#99AF0M000F9EF3F800")
```

Here is my code guys please go easy on me if i have not used the right terms i am so new to the programming world but it is interesting.

```
print("./productionreview -output test.csv", "--desired-orderno = ",input(),  "--desired-hardwareversion = ",input(), "--desired-softwareversion = ",input()," --pc-praefix",input(), "--desired-device-type=",input(), "--scancode=", "58183#99AF0M000F9EF3F800")

# Desired Values

# Timestamp
now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Eingabe von scancode
scancode_string = input()
scan_code_cropped_mac = scancode_string[12:]
scan_code_cropped_artikel = scancode_string[:5]
#print(scan_code_cropped_artikel)
#print(scan_code_cropped_mac)
print(scancode_string)

print("Current device information: ")
print(now)
print(100*"")

# Order number
print("Desired Order number:",d_ordernum)
print("Order number from scancode :",scan_code_cropped_artikel)
print("Ordernumber from wbm: ", ord_nmr)
if d_ordernum == ord_nmr == scan_code_cropped_artikel:
    print("Order number PASS")
else:
    print("Order number does not match")
print(100*"")

# Hardware version
print("Desired Hardware Version:",d_hw_version)
print("Hardware Version from wbm: ", v)
if d_hw_version == v:
    print("Hardware version PASS")
else:
    print("Wrong Hardware Version")
print(100*"")

# Software version
print("Desired Software Version:",d_sf_version)
print("Software Version from wbm: ", b)
if d_sf_version == b:
    print("Software version PASS")
else:
    print("Wrong Software Version")
print(100*"")

# Mac address
print("Mac address from scancode :",scan_code_cropped_mac)
print("Mac address from wbm: ", mac_addr)
list_of_chars = mac_addr.split(":")
mac_address_string_joined = ''.join(list_of_chars) 
if scan_code_cropped_mac == mac_address_string_joined:
    print("Correct MAC address")
else:
    print("Fail")
print(100*"")

d_product_code = pc_praefix + "-" + d_sf_version + "-" + d_hw_version
product_code = pc_praefix + "-" + b + "-" + v
print("Desired product code: ",d_product_code )
print("Product code of current device: ", product_code)
print(100*"")

print("Desired device type:",d_dev_typ)
print("Device type from wbm: ", dev_typ)
if d_dev_typ == dev_typ:
    print("Device type PASS")
else:
    print("Wrong device type")
print(100*"")
```

I could really use your suggestions and example code guys

Comment: Please consider shortening the code to only contain the specific part you want help with and reducing the wall of text as a lot of people will simply ignore it and move on. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how to create a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest (and the most pythonic) way to do it is by using the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module.

Here an example that will help you understand how to use it:

```
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is the description of your command line interface')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='The output file (example test.csv)', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--desired-orderno', help='Desired order', type=int, default=1000, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--desired-hardwareversion', help='Desired Hardware Version', required=True)
    # ...
    parser.add_argument('--scancode', help='Scancode')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(f'Output file: {args.output}')
    if args.scancode:
        print(f'Scancode: {args.scancode}')


main()
```

As you can see in this example, the module argparse is pretty easy to use.
You will need to define every argument.

You should try to use functions for your code, it will help you to define something easier to read / use :)

I hope it will help you enough.

Comment: Thank you very much i appreciate the help, i dove into the world of argparse thanks to you and figured it out